# Add bootloader in the appropriate paths in debian during upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade

I am currently in the process of upgrading an old machine from `debian9` to `debian10`.

At a certain point, I am presented with the following prompt::

[image]

Why is it offering me the option to install GRUB both on the device itself `/dev/sda` and its partition `/dev/sda1`?

What is the correct decision to make in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are useful in different scenarios, which is why both are available. In your case, follow the advice in the dialog and install Grub on `/dev/sda`.